# Use LINQ to match property values to Dictionary keys

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's suppose I have these 2 simple classes:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string name;
    public string objectProperty;
    [other properties]
}

public class Referencer
{
    public string name;
    public Dictionary<string, object> objectDictionary;
}
```

and a list of MyObject instances:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>
{
    new MyObject(name: "name1", objectProperty: "objectProperty1", other properties...),
    new MyObject(name: "name2", objectProperty: "objectProperty2", other properties...),
    new MyObject(name: "name3", objectProperty: "objectProperty3", other properties...),
    other myObjects...
}
```

and such dictionary of dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> sampleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    {"name3", new Dictionary<string, object> { {"property1", "value1"}, {"property2", "value2"}  }  },
    {"name2", new Dictionary<string, object> { {"property3", "value3"}, {"property4", "value4"}  }  },
    {"name1", new Dictionary<string, object> { {"property5", "value5"}, {"property6", "value6"}  }  },
    other entries...
};
```

I need to be able to create a `List<Referencer>` matching `myObjects` to `sampleDictionary` according to the rule:

```
myObjects.name == sampleDictionary.Key
```

I've tried to use LINQ `ForEach`, `Where`, `ToDictionary`, but I think I have something missing here and need your help.

Comment: It looks like you need a simple Select: `var result = myObjects.Select(o => new Referencer { name = o.name, objDicionary = sampleDictionary[o.name] }).ToList();`.

Comment: I do not quite understand the intention of the question but I think your @AleksAndreev comment is the right answer, so make it an answer :)

Comment: @AleksAndreev As always: simpler than I thought... Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Augmenting the answer of @AleksAndreev a bit:

```
myObjects
    .Where(x => sampleDictionary.ContainsKey(x))
    .Select(x => new Referencer { name = x.name, objectDictionary = sampleDictionary[x.name] });
```